# Storing a Database for a JavaFX program

Tags: java, database

I am currently developing a JavaFx program for a friend's company. I need to store information, so I am using an embedded database (mostly likely derby). Since the database needs to be outside of the application, I need to store it somewhere on the computer. *I am wondering where should I store the database on the personal computer?* Last time I created a similar application I just had the application and the database in the same folder, but that is very cumbersome and unappealing for users.

Comment: It depends.  Is your system designed for multiple users? What kind of data does it hold  - application data (a cookbook's recipe db), or user data for the application (theme preferences, custom short cuts/menus/key combos, bookmarks, etc)?  Both?  One needs to be shared between all users, one needs to be private to only one user... I'm a Linux guy, so `/usr/share/appname` or `~/.appname` or perhaps `~/.config/appname`

Answer (score 0):

FYI. JavaFX and JavaDB( Derby)  will have to be added as dependencies past Java 6.

That said, the derby database in production is created in the folder the .jar is executed from.

[Video with your answer](http://www.jeremiahstillings.net/wp/java-derby-help-for-se/)

Note that you can do this with a any RDBMS you choose too. It does not have to be derby.

Have a look at this

https://www.javatpoint.com/java-jdbc